# typsafe sortBy/orderBy on Spark Dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Given the following that is working fine:

```
myDF.as[MyCaseClass].sort("process_utc_sec")
```

How can I do a more typesafe way like:

```
myDF.as[MyCaseClass].sortBy(_.process_utc_sec)
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your DataSet to an RDD and call [`sortBy`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#sortBy%5BK%5D(f:T=%3EK,ascending:Boolean,numPartitions:Int)(implicitord:Ordering%5BK%5D,implicitctag:scala.reflect.ClassTag%5BK%5D):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD%5BT%5D) on this RDD. Then convert back to DataSet:

```
myDF.as[MyCaseClass].rdd.sortBy(_.process_utc.sec).toDS()
```

However there isn't any alternative for the [`sortWithinPartition`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#sortWithinPartitions(sortCol:String,sortCols:String*):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset%5BT%5D) method...